# converting 2012-07-04T17:30:52+00:00 to 2012-07-04T17:30:52Z

Tags: javascript, jquery

as far as I know both
 `2012-07-04T17:30:52+00:00` and
 `2012-07-04T17:30:52Z` are dates in **iso8601** format with time zone UTC.

I am using prettyDate jquery plugin. It accepts date only in the format `2012-07-04T17:30:52Z`

i am getting dates in the format `2012-07-04T17:30:52+00:00` as a response from json

so how can i convert `2012-07-04T17:30:52+00:00` to `2012-07-04T17:30:52Z` using javascript or jquery.

Comment: you could call `.replace(/\+00:00$/, "Z")` on the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smYKJ/)**

```
var serverSays = '2012-07-04T17:30:52+00:00';
var iWant = serverSays.split('+')[0] +'Z';
```